# Question not too localized

Tags: support, stack-overflow, specific-question, reopen-closed

This is idiotic, but this question:

[How do I catch exceptions thrown by Eigen's MatrixXd::resize() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246980/how-to-catch-an-exception-thrown-by-a-third-party-library)

really isn't too localized.

- Eigen is an actual tag-name on stackoverflow
- The question concerns catching exceptions issued by Eigen
- The solution is quite helpful

I'm not mad, I just think this is really stupid (I am mad).

Comment: Yes, not too localized, and ATM has 3 reopen votes, but you really need to play nicer.

Comment: The title certainly wasn't helping the case

Comment: Let's close this as too localized? ;D

Comment: *Inny meeny mieny mo, I feel grumpy and I'll close your question.*

Comment: Question is not open. Happy now? And change that title to something more meaningful.

Comment: I would close this as not a real question, because I can't get my mind past all these contradictory statements (are you referring to your question's closure or its unlocalizedness as idiotic, and are you mad or not?). But meta has no such close reason. Sulk.

Comment: You're not mad, but you're mad? Are you mad?

Comment: @random I didn't say anything about TIGERS here did I?

Comment: He's *mad*.  ***MAD I SAY!!!***

Comment: @BoltClock He's obviously been eating Starburst recently...

Comment: I am very, very mad.  Mad as a tiger.

Comment: @jadarnel27: "Wait - are you angry, or are you crazy?" "Yes."

Comment: On another note, something needs to be done about the anti-tiger sentiments on these sites.

Comment: @bob, *(shameless plug)*, see [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/102748/164403). To avoid being mad, try putting the joke in the mid-to-last lines of your question, not the first one :)

Comment: @minitech lol.  Oh, you crazy miniature technician.

Comment: Oh, the irony...

Comment: Gosh Robert you are so lame. Anyway I don't care.  It's still a good question and I think the people who downvoted/closed it did so on a strictly anti-tiger basis.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a site for "cute" titles or random tiger pictures. Resurrect WSOIN, add it.

Comment: The question was *extremely* localized except for people believing that all C++ exceptions are integers. About 4 persons world wide, is my guess.

Comment: @BoPersson Dude, back off. Your name is 1/4 the bo's in mine, so cool the insults.

Comment: Plus, "Bo" that is what stackoverflow _is for_.  For questions about programming languages. I'd like to see you try and make your case that asking if a C++ exception must have type `int` is "too localized". Go close [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976489/c-exceptions-int-or-stdexception) as "too localized" if you really believe so.

Comment: @bobobobo - Questions based on a misunderstanding are often closed  as "too localized", assuming that not many others will be asking themselves the same question. There are already lots of other questions about how exceptions work.

Comment: Actually I really like questions based on misunderstandings.  I didn't think this was too localized because I'm pretty sure there are more than _4_ people worldwide who will stumble upon the question. Only time will tell.